# How to program an interrupt that is not dependent on GPIO?

Tags: gpio, interrupts

You can program an interrupt so that the Pi can wait for something like a rising edge on one of its GPIO ports.

But, can you program an interrupt for an event that is not GPIO dependent? For example: the Pi is perhaps doing a sequence of turning on and off some LEDs and when the user presses a button (not a keyboard interrupt) the sequence reverses.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: An interrupt upon pressing a button that is not keyboard nor GPIO. Sounds like a riddle to me.

Comment: Welcome -- but this is not really a [pi specific question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).   It's a general programming question ([Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)).   I believe what you are really interested in is the concept of [*event*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)); of which an [*interrupt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) is a specific form.

Comment: @Ghanima, you're right. I made a mistake. I meant that is not a CTRL+C interrupt.

Comment: @goldilocks, thank you. I did not know interrupts are a form of an event.

Comment: A "event" can be pretty much anything that's handled *asynchronously*, although that wikipedia article is a bit confusing in that it refers to passing them up from an "event loop" which works synchronously.  Synchronous refers to doing things in a particular order;  asynchronous refers to handling things that happen arbitrarily (such as an interrupt).  A defining aspect of an interrupt is that it comes from hardware via the operating system (or perhaps is generated by the OS) whereas the broader concept of event would include things generated in user code.  I.e., yes you can generate *events*.

Comment: So, even though my question isn't really Pi specific, what I still want to know is if the Pi can handle events.

Comment: If it's a computer, it handles events, lol.  Put another way, it's a core [high level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language) software concept.   For example, a user clicking a button in a GUI is an event, but it is not really an interrupt, even though an interrupt (from pushing the mouse button) may be involved on some *lower* level.   The specifics of all this depend upon what language you are using, etc.

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you very much. It was very clear. I think I have a better idea of where to look now.

Comment: To clarify that last part a bit: although pushing a mouse button generates an interrupt, it says nothing about where the mouse pointer on the screen is.   That is completely determined by software, which passes an event referring to a specific GUI button up to a higher level, where it is handled as an event pretty much the same way you would handle a GPIO event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Linux you can't program an interrupt.  Linux handles interrupts.  If you are talking about bare metal then yes, you can program interrupts.

You can ask Linux for a callback when an interrupt is detected (or probably about 50µs after at least on a Pi.).

- A callback may be for a timed event (example after 5 seconds).
- A callback may be because a file descriptor has data ready (example,
  someone has written data to a file, someone has read data from a
  file, a gpio has changed state, gpios are treated as files by Linux).
- A callback may be because your process has been sent a signal
  (example ctrl-c from the user, or from another process).

I'm sure there are others but these are the ones I normally use.